# How to fix Monospacing for Unusual characters on Windows?

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, cross-browser, monospace

I have some output on my screen in a pre with a monospaced font. It shows up correctly on Mac on both Chrome and Firefox. However, on Windows, it loses its monospacing.

Here's an example from [my site](http://www.learneroo.com/modules/44/nodes/241):

```
▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥
▥♖.......▥
▥........▥
▥........▥
▥........▥
▥........▥
▥........▥
▥........▥
▥.......☆▥
▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥
```

How do I fix it so each character takes the same amount of space, even on Windows?

Here's some more test text:

```
0123456789
..........
▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥▥
```

Update:
It seems its an issue with how Windows displays certain characters, like ▥. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: No too sure how to explain, so i make a comment. reset font-family and font-size like to verdana 20px or whatever. Notice that even then , fonts do not look from the family the chess piece for instance..

Comment: @GCyrillus, if I change the font to Veranda, there won't be any monospacing.

Comment: Your page is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.learneroo.com%2Fmodules%2F44%2Fnodes%2F241&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices). Please fix the issues first, because otherwise browser behaviour is at least "unpredictable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Computed Styles tab in Chrome, the reason for the issue is it is getting the glyphs from three different font faces:

```
Courier New -- 72 Glyphs
Lucida Sans Unicode -- 36 Glyphs
Arial Unicode MS -- 2 glyphs
```

Each of these faces will have different sizing.

### Possible Solutions

- Replace border glyphs with css border
- Replace 'empty' cells with a glyph from the same area as the chess pieces, possibly U+3000 "ideographic space":
- use something like a `ul` or even flexbox to display the elements - gives the advantage of being able to select each element programatically!

Good luck

Comment: I'd like to see if I can fix it without changing the output.

Comment: then you may have to use a webfont that contains all the glyphs you need - then you know it will render cross-browser

Comment: In Chrome on Mac, I just have `Menlo Regular—109 glyphs`. So I need to get a font like that for Windows. http://superuser.com/questions/59456/any-good-way-to-get-the-new-menlo-font-on-windows

Comment: Or of course go svg ... do you need to support old browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS property `letter-spacing`.

```
// probably use a more explicit css selector than pre, but this works
pre {
  letter-spacing: 12px;
}
```

Result;

[image]

**Edit;**

I misunderstood, while it looks nicer with some letter-spacing, that wasn't the problem. Just had a look around for a clean solution but was unable to find anything. The two solutions I can suggest are;

1. Wrapping each character in a `<span>` and giving the span a width.
2. Find a new font that works.

I'll continue to have a look around and see if I can find anything.